# How to structure my angularjs app and test folder

Tags: angularjs

In my root folder 'Client' I would like to put an 'app' and 'test' folder inside the 'Client' folder. But I have no experience wether this works fine when adding libraries/generators to each of the folders.

Should there be a problem or what is the advised way to do it right that my testing works correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use yeoman for scaffolding, however it requires installing both npm and yo.

http://yeoman.io/gettingstarted.html

```
npm install -g generator-angular
```

Comment: Thanks, I just did this and saw there is a app AND test folder generator out of the box so I will stick to that!

Comment: @HelloWorld I would not recommend the standard angular application structure unless you're working on a small web application. I'd recommend following Google's guide as it will provide you with more flexibility in scaling your application: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

Answer (score 3):

I find a good way to get started is by using npm init from your terminal.  It will create your packages.json file. Ideally you would have a basic layout like this:

```
app
    -css
    -images
    -js
        -controllers, views, services, directives, ect
    -libs (third party libs from bower)
tests
    -e2e
    -unit
node_modules
    -modules installed by npm
```

I created a angular template I like to use less the test folder.  you can access it here: 
https://github.com/breck421/angular-template.  For example you would just add a test folder at the root.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem. But here are some guidelines:

http://www.jacopretorius.net/2013/07/angularjs-best-practices.html

Yeoman angular-js generator providing a good start structure with some nice grunt tasks: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Answer (score 0):

These references may be useful if you are building larger apps with angular:

- [Best Practice Recommendations for Angular App Structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub)
- Discussed at length [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/109)